# reactjs app gmail login issue when deploy on django server

Tags: reactjs, django, google-cloud-platform, gmail

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'


import {googleLogout, useGoogleLogin  } from '@react-oauth/google';
```

mport {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';

```
import { Link as ReactLink } from "react-router-dom";

import axios from 'axios';
```

import './App.css';

```
function Homepage(){

const navigate = useNavigate();
const [ user, setUser ] = useState([]);
const [ profile, setProfile ] = useState([]);

const login = useGoogleLogin({
    onSuccess: (codeResponse) => {setUser(codeResponse); navigate('/instructions');},
    onError: (error) => {console.log('Login Failed:', error);}
});
useEffect(
    () => {
        console.log('user:: ',user);
        if (user.length != 0) {
            axios
                .get(`https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=${user.access_token}`, {
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: `Bearer ${user.access_token}`,
                        Accept: 'application/json'
                    }
                })
                .then((res) => {
                    console.log('result:: ',res.data)
                    setProfile(res.data);
                })
                .catch((err) => console.log('err',err));
        }
    },
    [ user ]
);
return (
        <div className="homepage">
         <div id="customBtn" className="customGPlusSignIn" onClick={() => login()}>
        </div>
)
}

export default Homepage;
```

**    when i am deploying this reactjs webapp on tomcat local server it is working fine and routing to               instructions page but if i am deploying it on django server (generating build file and integrating that with django backend project)then getting issues like page is appearing but when i click on login button it opens popup for select account and then it goes to same login page, no error is coming on console as well as on    terminal,it should redirect to instructions page but it's not.
Note:- 1.)i have added cors line on settings.py file
2.)i have also check the redirect urls on google cloud console.
3.)After integrating with django, all the UI components are working and routing as well except gmail login.**

```
**I am expecting that it should route to instructions page after click onto login button.

i have added few things like cors lines:**
```

`` `MIDDLEWARE=[  "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware", ``
`"django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware"]`
`CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True`
`CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [`
``` '``http://localhost:3000``', ```
`]`

```
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
'http://localhost:3000',
'http://127.0.0.1:8000'
]
`
```